# Material Design Lite Carousel

Tags: material-design-lite

I am building a web application using Angular 4. For designing, I am using material design lite. However, I want to implement an interactive carousel using MDL that gives me smooth look and feel and goes well with my navbar but I cannot find any documentation for it on the web. Is it possible to do so?  [mynavbar-mdl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmaFh.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you're looking for? http://leifoolsen.github.io/mdl-ext/demo/carousel.html

Comment: I have added a picture of my nav-bar. I am looking for something that goes well with it.